# Ajax Call Request every 5 Seconds And Wait Before Sending The Request Until The Previous Request Is sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send ajax Request every 5 seconds And each request waits until the previous request is sent successfully , This is my code it works but it sends requests even if the previous request was not sent successfully.

Here My Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sending").show();
    $("#send").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#send").attr('value', "Sending ...");

    var ajax_call = function() {

      $.ajax({
        url: "fbshr.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          postURL: $('#postURL').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $(data).appendTo($("#response")).before("");
          $('#response').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#response').prop("scrollHeight")
          }, 500);
          $("#num-msg-1").html($('#response p.alert-success').length);
          $("#num-msg-2").html($('#response p.alert-danger').length);

        }
      });
    };

    var interval = 5000;

    setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
  });
});
```

Comment: Remove `setInterval` - that will fire regardless of what's happened.   Inside the `success:` callback add `setTimeout(ajax_call, interval)`

Comment: @freedomn-m It works, but it doubles the number of requests each time

Comment: Make sure it's `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`

Comment: @freedomn-m i'm sure here The full code  https://jsfiddle.net/yeosxtw3/

Comment: Yes, setInterval is inappropriate here, should use setTimeout.  But putting the setTimeout inside the success callback will make the next call be 5 seconds after the previous one *finishes*, not 5 seconds after it *starts*.  If you want a true "run every 5 seconds if you can, but don't overlap calls", that's a bit trickier.

Comment: How many times do you expect this to loop? 5 times? 10 times? 1000 times? This sounds like you need a recursive solution. Post data, get success, in success wait 5 seconds and Post data... This is not a good idea if it's going to repeat a large number of times. Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.